# how to fix a select in selenium-side-runner which is working in selenium-ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I try to run my test in cmd selenium-side-runner which is working in selenium-ide but it s not working, it cant find the select a dropdown and this is the error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73m0B.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No me. And you?